# JavaScript How to Create a Function that returns a string with number of times a characters shows up in a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to make a function that takes a string. Then it needs to return a string with each letter that appears in the function along with the number of times it appears in the string. For instance "eggs" should return e1g2s1.

```
function charRepString(word) {
  var array = [];
  var strCount = '';
  var countArr = [];
 

 // Need an Array with all the characters that appear in the String
 for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
   if (array.indexOf(word[i]) === false) {
     array.push(word[i]);
   }
 }
 // Need to iterate through the word and compare it with each char in the Array with characters and save the count of each char.
 for (var j = 0; j < word.length; i++) {
   
   for (var k = 0; k < array.length; k++){ 
   var count = 0;
   if (word[i] === array[k]){
     count++;
   }
   countArr.push(count);
 }
 // Then I need to put the arrays into a string with each character before the number of times its repeated.
 
 
 return strCount;
}

console.log(charRepString("taco")); //t1a1co1
console.log(charRepString("egg")); //e1g2
```

Comment: why `t1a1co1` but not `t1a1c1o1`

Comment: `[...new Set(word.split(''))].map(c => \`${c}${word.split(c).length - 1}\`).join('')`

Comment: What about `java`? Is it `j1a1v1a1` or `j1a2v1`

Comment: And does the result need to be in a particular order? Ie for an input of `taco` is `a1c1o1t1` also a avalid output? Or does it have to be `t1a1c1o1`?

Comment: Sorry it should of been t1a1c1o1.

Comment: So if you are trying to grab a value and the number of times that value occurs its best to use an object to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let str = prompt('type a string ') || 'taco'

function getcount(str) {
  str = str.split('')
  let obj = {}
  for (i in str) {
    let char = str[i]
    let keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
    if (keys.includes(char)) {
      obj[char] += 1
    } else {
      obj[char] = 1
    }
  }
  let result = ''
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach((prop) => {
    result += prop + obj[prop]
  })
  return result
}

console.log(getcount(str))
```

Comment: What happens if you enter "10za"? `0111a1z1` does not seems like the right output.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the alphanumeric symbols matters

```js
const str = "10zza";

const counted = [...[...str].reduce((m, s) => (
  m.set(s, (m.get(s) || 0) + 1), m
), new Map())].flat().join("");

console.log(counted); // "1101z2a1"
```

Or also like (as suggested by *Bravo*):

```js
const str = "10zza";

const counted = [...new Set([...str])].map((s) =>
  `${s}${str.split(s).length-1}`
).join("");

console.log(counted); // "1101z2a1"
```

Answer (score 0):

A more clear and verbose solution-

Let `m` be max number of symbols in charset

Time complexity- `O(n log(m))`

Space complexity- `O(m)`

```js
function countFrequencies(str) {
  const freqs = new Map()
  
  for (const char of str) {
    const prevFreq = freqs.get(char) || 0
    freqs.set(char, prevFreq + 1)
  }
  
  return freqs
}

function getCountStr(str) {
  const freqs = countFrequencies(str)
  const isListed = new Set()
  const resultArray = []
  
  for (const char of str) {
    if (isListed.has(char)) continue
    resultArray.push(char)
    resultArray.push(freqs.get(char))
    isListed.add(char)
  }
  
  return resultArray.join("")
}

console.log(getCountStr("egg"))
console.log(getCountStr("taco"))
console.log(getCountStr("10za"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Set** constructor, first we will get the unique data.

```js
function myfun(str){
    let createSet = new Set(str);
    let newArr = [...createSet].map(function(elem){
      return `${elem}${str.split(elem).length-1}`
    });
    let newStr = newArr.join('');
    console.log(newStr);
}
myfun('array');
```